# Set a parent working directory then calling on subfolders R

Tags: r, directory, setwd

Basic question sorry and probably already answered but having trouble searching for a solution.

I want to work on some data file:
`C:/Users/userg/desktop/R/harv/trial1/short/data/file_name.csv`

1. So in global settings I set my default working directory to:
   `C:/Users/userg/desktop/R`
2. when I start a session I want to focus on this project by writing:
   `setwd("harv/trial1/short")`
3. and when I load my data I want to write:
   `df<- read_csv("data/file_name.csv")`

I normally just write:
`setwd("C:/Users/userg/desktop/R/harv/trial1/short")`
at the opening of the session and then use 3.

Is there a way I can do what I want or do I have to just keep writing out the full path every time?

Cheers